# Final value theorem for transfer functions with more than one pole at origin

Tags: transfer-function

One browsing Wikipedia for final value theorem, it is said that final value theorem cannot be used for transfer functions with more than one pole at origin. Why? Can you give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about your question a long time until I found out that someone has already asked [nearly the same question on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771167/why-does-the-final-value-theorem-not-hold-for-a-transfer-function-with-more-than).

The answer there is equal to the results I got after a lot of thinking:

\$\lim_{s\to 0}sH(s)\$ does not exist in the case of two poles at the origin.

However: Why does Wikipedia write that a check is necessary in this case?

I can only guess but **maybe** you'll have to take the sentence in Wikipedia literally:

> There are two checks performed ... which **confirm valid results** ...

You could understand this sentence in a way that these checks guarantee you:

- That a result exists at all (check 2) and
- That this result is valid (check 1)

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's some qualification of the statement, it's incorrect. I can give an example (of many!) where it does work: \$\frac{1}{ s^2} \rightarrow t\$ has a final value of \$\infty\$, which is the same as limit\$\frac{1}{s},\: \small s\rightarrow 0\$